# MS Access crosstab, counting duplicated values

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

Is is possible to create a crosstab on MS access, when the value you get from counting the number of LC cards.

For example my data set.

```
Store     LC number

Store1    111  

Store1    222    

Store1    333 

Store2    111

Store2    444 

Store2    555
```

Create a crosstab on MS Access (count LC numbers), because 111 is in boths stores you add the count to both stores.

```
         store1  store2 
Store1    3         1    
Store2    1         3
```

Currently I only manage to create crosstab, but do not know how to count the LC numbers that are in both stores.

```
         store1  store2 
Store1    3             
Store2             3
```

Comment: Each store only has 3 items but in your example you want 4 items returned.

Comment: Yes, 4 because LC number 111 is repeating in both stores.

Comment: You would have to go to considerable lengths to force a database to return a count of four when there are only three items.

Comment: I have no idea how the dseired output is related in any way to the input and vice versa. Maybe show your current query...

Comment: For example the person with LC number 111 goes to the shop 1 and 2. Because of that, I am looking for a way to show that one person is using both stores.

Comment: Design your query with customer (LC Number) as row variable and store as column variable.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. But is there a way to summarise the information? Because currently there are +100 rows with the LC numbers. And at the same time show that one person is using both stores.

Comment: Solved my problem with excel and sumifs. Thanks for the input guys.